# Grep doesn't work when trying to match a word from a file in a second file

Tags: bash, grep

I've got 2 files, both with numerous lines that only contain one number. I'm trying to see if any number from file1 matches a number in file2. This is what I tried, and for some reason it doesn't work:

`for i in $(cat file1); do grep ${i} file2; done`

Fore reference here is data from file1 and file2

```
file1   file2
2134    1251
2135    5626
5342    4327
6456    8453
3413    4537
4525    3533
2347    5738
1235    1235
7453    3462
```

So shouldn't this command take each line from file 1 and grep it against the whole of file2? In that case, shouldn't a match be printed on screen?

Comment: It *should* - but you would probably be advised to use something like `grep -Fwf file1 file2` instead

Comment: It should but it consistently doesn't, even if I do it on the same file like `for i in $(cat file1); do grep ${i} file1; done` it still doesn't work. I'll try your advice

Comment: Notice: I just tryed your code and works for me. Is there any chance that file1 contains hidden characters? ... may be \0 or \r or tabs?

Comment: if what you really wants is to compare the files, you might want to use `sort`, `uniq` and `diff` (or `kompare` or `k3diff` or any other file comparison tool)

Comment: With those columns of numbers in two files, and that command, I get the `1235` as output, it seems to be the lone duplicate. In other words, I can't see an issue with the result here. Of course if the data is broken, like CRLF line endings in `file1` but not in `file2`, then you'd have problems.

Comment: Yes I think the problem was the line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two ordinary Unix text files, your shell loop prints

```
1235
```

since this is the line that occurs in both files. If it does not, then one of your files may be a DOS text file. You can convert DOS text files into Unix text files with the `dos2unix` utility.

There is nothing major wrong with your loop given the type of data that you have, apart from the fact that it calls `grep` once for *every* line in `file1`.  It also would match substrings, for example `100` in `1001`, and it would, if any line in `file1` contained spaces or tabs, split these lines into multiple words (due to the `for i in $(cat ...)` where the `$(cat ...)` is unquoted).

If you want to solve your issue *this* way (with a loop), you would better do

```
while IFS= read -r word; do
    grep -xF -e "$word" file2
done <file1
```

The `-x` and `-F` are explained later in my answer, and `-e` signifies that the next argument is the pattern to match with (otherwise, it may be taken as a command line option if it starts with a dash (`-`).

This would still execute `grep` once for each line in `file1`, but it would do it correctly.

---

To extract lines in `file2` that exactly correspond to line in `file1`, without using a shell loop, you would use

```
$ grep -xF -f file1 file2
1235
```

This is assuming that `file1` contains a *reasonable* number of lines, but not too many ("too many" will depend on the amount of memory that you have).

The command uses `grep` with `-x`, which forces matches across full lines only (no substring matches), and with `-F` which changes `grep` to do string comparisons rather than regular expression matches.

The `-f file1` instructs `grep` to read the patterns (the strings to match with) from `file1`.

---

For really massive amounts of data, it would be hugely inefficient to use `grep` though. Instead, for this task and with this type of data (single words on individual lines), it would be better to do a relational join operation between the files:

```
$ join file1 file2
1235
```

This would, *assuming that both files are lexicographically sorted*, return the numbers that are the same between both files.

---

Using `comm`:

```
$ comm -1 -2 file1 file2
1235
```

`comm` also compares *sorted* files and can easily handle *very* large datasets. It prints three columns by default:

1. lines that occur in the first file only
2. lines that occur in the second file only
3. lines that occurs in both files

With `-1` we turn off the output of the first column, and with `-2` we disable the second column, leaving `comm` to only output the lines that are the same in both files.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use `grep -f file1 file2` OR you may also use `cat file1 | grep -f /dev/stdin file2`

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Please note that a) a good answer explains what you do, so others can not just use it, but learn from it and b) without specifying `-x` or `-w` to grep you can get unwanted results if not all numbers are four-digit numbers like in the example (like `234` in `file1` ould match `1234` in `file2`). That was probably the reason for someone to downvote your answer (sadly, without leaving a comment)